# What is the equivalent word for "walking like a king"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a phrase or an vocabulary that means "walking like a king".

Comment: There is none. You will have to use an adverb, like *majestically* or what have you. Which is the whole point of having adverbs in the first place: so you don't need a dedicated verb for everything.

Comment: Ditto to Reg's comment - every synonym for walking or parambulating is made "kingly" with adverbs like "stately", "regal", etc.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: What if you're not allowed to use adverbs? Like in Strunk and White or Orwell?

Comment: Do you know if there is one and just can't remember it, or is there one in your native language and hope their to be an exact translation in English, or are you just wondering?

Comment: option, i read somewhere and can't remember now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swagger** is To walk with an air of overbearing confidence.

**Strut** is to walk with a vain, pompous bearing, as with head erect and chest thrown out, as if expecting to impress observers.

**Sashay** is to move or walk in a showy way, parade.

**Flaunt** is to parade or display oneself conspicuously, defiantly, or boldly.

Comment: I would think the *queen* would be "sashaying about" (no pun intended).

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what aspect of kingliness you want to capture.  Without more information, I would suggest **stride**, to walk deliberately with long, measured steps.

Answer (score 0):

"[Promenade](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/promenade)", when used as a verb implies that the subject is of public interest. It would be an appropriate word in this context.